# Possible closure issue: Why does d3 onResize function affect only the last element in my loop?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, responsive-design

I have a function that draws a chart with D3. I user this function on two elements on my web page. When the browser loads the page, both charts load. But when I resize my window, only the last chart resizes.

My code:

```
function drawChart(key, containerName){
    // lots of D3 code that draws a chart
}

var obj=    {
    "key1": "id1",
    "key2": "id2"
};

for(var key in obj) {
    var containerName=  obj[key];
    drawChart(key, containerName);

    d3.select(window).on("resize",function(){
        var svgID=      containerName+"-svg";
        var svgElement= document.getElementById(svgID);
        document.getElementById(containerName).removeChild();

        drawChart(key, containerName);
    });
}
```

What must I change so that both charts are redrawn when my window resizes?

Comment: yes, it's a closure issue ... key will always be the last key in obj in the resize callback

Comment: I wouldn't bind multiple window resize events in a loop, I'd use `d3.select(window).on("resize", redrawAll)` and then code `redrawAll()`  to use the loop to (re)draw the required charts. (This would avoid the closure issue.)